# How do I delay a function by X amount of ticks?

Tags: python, function, delay

Okay, so I have a hook that is called when a key is pressed, for example spacebar. What I want to do is, when this happens, I want to call a function. The next tick, I want to call a different function.

```
import pygame

def func1():
    do_things
def func2():
    do_other_things

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
            func1()
            #wait(1, func2)
```

Obviously #wait is replaced with however a 1-tick delay might be done.

Is there a way to do this? I'm guessing it's either a basic functionality I missed, or something incredibly complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
func2timer = -1
while True:
    if func2timer >= 0:
        func2timer -= 1
    if func2timer == 0:
        func2()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
            func1()
            func2timer = 1
```

(You can adjust timer to more than 1 if you want to wait more ticks)

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to flag whether or not to call `func2` when the time comes:

```
shouldDoFunc2 = false
while True:
    if shouldDoFunc2:
        func2()
        shouldDoFunc= false
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.K_SPACE:
            func1()
            shouldDoFunc2()
```